# 2 instanced of ESP8266Ping

Tags: class

I'm using `ESP8266Ping` lib inside my `iot` lib which hanldes Wifi connectivity and MQTT messages. Since it create its own instance called `Ping` when calling `#include <ESP8266Ping.h>`- it had to be place in `iot.cpp`.

I writing another library, `IPmonitor` which checks clients on the network (using pings), I wanted to use `ESP8266Ping` again.

My sketch file, create an instance of `iot` and `IPmonitor` for check/ log errors on monitored clients.

But I get error of using the same library twice.

I guess that since `ESP8366Ping.h` library is defined it creates an instance of the class ( see mark below ):

```
class PingClass {
  public:
    PingClass();

    bool ping(IPAddress dest,   byte count = 5);
    bool ping(const char* host, byte count = 5);

    int averageTime();

  protected:
    static void _ping_sent_cb(void *opt, void *pdata);
    static void _ping_recv_cb(void *opt, void *pdata);

    IPAddress _dest;
    ping_option _options;

    static byte _expected_count, _errors, _success;
    static int _avg_time;
};

#include "ESP8266Ping.impl.h"
PingClass Ping;                     // <----- This

#endif
```

How can it be solved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that library... you can't. All the code is in one big monolithic .h file. As you well know by now that is a big no-no. The author should be given a big slap on the wrists.

The closest you could do without re-writing the whole library is to just copy the class definition from the outer .h file and create an `extern` to the existing object - maybe make your own copy of the `ESP8266Ping.h` file without the `#include "ESP8266Ping.impl.h"` and `PingClass Ping;` (the latter of which you change to an `extern`).

Comment: Thank you. Since I don’t any future mishappens after lib update, I’ll probably use calling external function in ‘IPmonitor’ to call the relevant function from ‘iot’ class. And slapping

Comment: @Guy.D I have submitted a pull request with the required changes. You may like to test with my fork: https://github.com/majenkotech/ESP8266Ping

Comment: Well... this is very nice of you! Cheers